# How to supply password to a java process

Tags: java, bash, passwords, parameter-passing

I'm using a bash script to start a java program/process. The bash script prompts for username and password and should supply these to the java process. I don't want to supply these as parameters for the java program so they can be seen as clear text using the shell "ps" command. So I don't want any of the following:

```
 - java MyClass <clearTextPassword>
 - java -Dpass=<clearTextPassword>
```

Are there any recommended ways to supply the password to the java process from a shell script?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Best regards Trym

Comment: I assume that you can not modify the java part so that it asks for the password itself?

Answer (score 4):

if you have coded the program yourself, its better to design your program such that it promts the user for password and use [Console](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Console.html) class's [readPassword()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Console.html#readPassword%28%29) to read the password from the command line

Comment: I guess the only disadvantage would be that you couldn't script the program to run at some interval automatically since it will be reading stdin each time.

Comment: yes. In this approach user should be available to input password while running.

Comment: In the shell script I start java using nohup, so I guess that the console is not available?

Comment: [System.console()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#console%28%29) will return the console your application is connected to if it is connected, otherwise it returns null

Answer (score 2):

In this cases I create a file on disk (encrypted or not depending on your level of security need). I modify the permission so that only controlled user can read it when executing the program

Answer (score 1):

You could store the password in a properties file (you have different options when it comes to securing it.  You can also forgo a password entirely and use a public Key

Answer (score 1):

You could pass a hashed version of the password. For example, provide a timestamp, and a MD5 of timestamp and password concatenated together. This is of course if you have control over the process code and can work with an hashed version.

Comment: Well what difference an hashcode will make , still if a person gets hold of the hash value , the program can be execute the code  nevertherless

Comment: you could do a hash(timestamp+pwd), therefore a replay attack is not possible without using the same timestamp - which you could detect.